# How to find the option "Text Entry" for the keyboard on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: keyboard-layout, 19.04

At Ubuntu 19.04, I did not find the option *Text Entry* that allows us to change it to *US International* and accept accentuation. We can do it in previous versions, but it does not exist anymore on this new version.

Do you know any alternative?

Comment: Are you using Gnome or unity?  It is still in same place in unity.  Could not get gnome settings to work.

Comment: Have you added the keyboard layout from **system Settings > Region and Language > Input Sources (bottom window) > Plus icon (+)**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is *Input Sources*, located in Settings → *Region & Language*.